# How do I access an array inside an array of objects in a React Native ```FlatList```?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I would like to print each value associated with `name` inside the nested `services` array of each object in in a React Native `FlatList` like the example given below.

Example of data:

```
[
    {
        "id": "5fff179dc547a06fbc2351db",
        "categoryId": "5fca531b5843c949636cc679",
        "services": [
            {
                "id": "5fff17f4c547a06fbc2351dd",
                "name": "name",
                "description": "name",
                "durationInMinutes": 30,
                "price": 40,
                "categoryId": "5fff179dc547a06fbc2351db",
                "businessId": "5ff87018850be942ec31c39d"
            }
         ],
         "businessId": "5ff87018850be942ec31c39d"
    },
    {
        "id": "5fff179dc547a06fbc2351dc",
        "categoryId": "5fca531b5843c949636cc67a",
        "services": [],
        "businessId": "5ff87018850be942ec31c39d"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to map through the main array, then map through the services array within the main array item and return the "name" field.

First, set the array equal to a constant.

```
const list = [
  {
      "id": "5fff179dc547a06fbc2351db",
      "categoryId": "5fca531b5843c949636cc679",
      "services": [
          {
              "id": "5fff17f4c547a06fbc2351dd",
              "name": "name",
              "description": "name",
              "durationInMinutes": 30,
              "price": 40,
              "categoryId": "5fff179dc547a06fbc2351db",
              "businessId": "5ff87018850be942ec31c39d"
          }
      ],
      "businessId": "5ff87018850be942ec31c39d"
  },
  {
      "id": "5fff179dc547a06fbc2351dc",
      "categoryId": "5fca531b5843c949636cc67a",
      "services": [],
      "businessId": "5ff87018850be942ec31c39d"
  }
]
```

Then map through the array.

```
list.map((item) => {
  return item.services.map(service => {
    return console.log(service.name)
})
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer